# Should we use multiple inheritance to redefine X() and call inherited X() from each superclass?

Tags: class-design

We have 4 classes.

- `Field`
- `ForbiddenField` inherits from `Field`
- `RequiredField` inherits from `Field`
- `ForbiquiredField` : the subject of my question

I would like to define a function `Validate()`in `ForbiquiredField`, originaly defined in `ForbiddenField` and `RequiredField`.
I would like to use both of functions `X()` defined in `ForbiddenField` and `RequiredField`.
Is it a good deal to define:

```
ForbiquiredField inherits ForbiddenField, RequiredField
{
    Validate()
    {
        ForbiddenField.Validate();
        RequiredField.Validate();
        /// Some specific tasks
    }
}
```

Or is there a better way to proceed?

Comment: What language are you using? Quite a few popular languages don't support multiple inheritance.

Comment: Arguments about Downvotes are Welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate from Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456154/does-c-sharp-support-multiple-inheritance/2456234

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I don't think it would provide any clarification but ok : It's Webdev22

Comment: Foo Bar examples seldom provide any insight, because you haven't captured your specific requirements in your problem domain.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't get the goal of your comment

Comment: Instead of saying ClassB and ClassC, use the actual names from your problem domain, like Player and Weapon, or Customer and Product.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Edited my Question. Thanks for the advice, I did not understand at the first time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to the [Diamond Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). Either the language that offers multiple inheritance has explicit support to avoid the related problems, or your best bet is to **avoid (multiple) inheritance**.

Let me recapitulate the problem in pseudocode:

```java
class ClassA { X() { ... } }
class ClassB extends ClassA { X() { ClassA.X(); ... } }
class ClassC extends ClassA { X() { ClassA.X(); ... } }
class ClassD extends ClassB, ClassC {
  X() { ClassB.X(); ClassC.X(); ... }
}
```

In this design where ClassB and ClassC also call their super method in ClassA, a call to `ClassD.X()` will end up calling `ClassA.X()` *twice*. This is the depth-first resolution approach to multiple inheritance as used in C++ and may or may not be what you want.

Other languages try to order (“linearize”) the base classes so that we can simply call the next base class, without knowing in advance which class that will be. Python is one such language:

```python
class ClassA(object):
  def x(self):
     ...

class ClassB(ClassA):
  def x(self):
    super().x(); ...

class ClassC(ClassA):
  def x(self):
    super().x(); ...

class ClassD(ClassB, ClassC):
  def x(self):
    super().x(); ...
```

For ClassD, the C3 method resolution order (MRO) algorithm will order the classes as `ClassD, ClassB, ClassC, ClassA` and searches the classes for methods left-to-right. The `super().x()` call does not call into the base class, but continues the search in the MRO for that object. So in this case, the super-call from the `ClassB.x()` method will actually be resolved to `ClassC.x()`. There are limitations to this approach:

- This requires explicit support from the language's object model. It is not a feature that can be retro-fit later.
- The resulting MRO can be unintuitive, because it doesn't necessarily dispatch to the base class, but could dispatch to seemingly unrelated classes.
- All classes in a multiple inheritance hierarchy must cooperate. Everyone must forward the `super().x()` calls correctly, or this will break. If different classes require different arguments, passing the arguments can be tricky (this is frequently an issue with Python's `__init__()` method that serves as a constructor).

Because of these problems, very few languages support real multiple inheritance (most notably Python, C++, and Perl). Even in these languages, multiple inheritance is generally discouraged. Other languages use *traits* or *mixins* to provide some aspects of multiple inheritance, without having to define a complicated method resolution order.

In a scenario where you want to dynamically add functionality to some object, the **decorator pattern** could be more appropriate. It only needs interface inheritance, and completely avoids the problems of class inheritance.

1. Define an interface like `interface CanDoX { X(); }`
2. Provide a base implementation, e.g. `class ClassA implements CanDoX { ... }`
3. Implement various decorators that implement `CanDoX` and take a `CanDoX` instance in their constructor:

   ```java
   class DecorateXWithB implements CanDoX {
     private CanDoX base;
     X() { base.X(); ... }
   }
   ```
4. You can now assemble a pipeline of decorators in exactly the order you want:

   ```java
   new DecorateXWithD(
       new DecorateXWithC(
           new DecorateXWithB(
               new ClassA(...))))
   ```